# Java Persistence: join different columns dependent on runtime parameter

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, orm, spring-data-jpa

Consider the following example:

[image: Example]

I want to use JPA/Hibernate to query objects on the left, while directly joining the labels. Which label column to use, however, is determined by a dynamic session parameter. For some users it is "English" and for others it is "German". Hence, my join needs to target a column which is only defined at runtime in the dynamic variable scope.

I see the following (theoretical) solutions:

1. Do not use join and query for the label afterwards
2. Let the join address a column based on a runtime parameter
3. Make the language a column and use a composite key to join the label (while supplying the runtime parameter as second part of the composite key)
4. Use a view to create two distinct translation tables (one for German, one for English); use the runtime parameter to dynamically join with different tables

Whereas solution 1 is feasible, it is inefficient and involves a lot of boilerplate code. On the other hand, I was not able to come up with practical solutions for 2-4.

Further, given that the labels have to be managed by the database - what is the best practice solution for this kind of use case?

Comment: 'my join needs to target a column which is only defined at runtime in the dynamic variable scope' - I don't see how. Aren't you always joining on `Label_ID = ID`?

Comment: As a side note, how often are translations going to change? Unless they can be modified from outside your application, I'd seriously consider caching them in memory

Comment: @crizzis Yes, we always join on `Label_ID = ID`. The question is rather which data column of both (German/English) to use, to populate the attribute. The strings are actually from outside our application, that's why we need the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Provided there is a parameter with kind of languageCode, I assume that this problem can be solved with `CASE` clause, similar to this:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.location, CASE WHEN (?1 = 1) THEN t1.english ELSE t1.german END AS label 
FROM Location t0  INNER JOIN Translation t1  ON (t0.label_id = t1.id)
```

and the query can be built with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
public List<TranslatedLocation> getTranslatedLocations(int langCode) {
    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Location l,
                                       Translation t) -> {

        String trans = CASE(WHEN(langCode == 1).THEN(t.getEnglish())
                                               .ELSE(t.getGerman())).END();
        String label = alias(trans, TranslatedLocation::getLabel);

        SELECT(l.getId(), l.getLocation(), label);
        FROM(l).JOIN(t).ON(l.getTranslation() == t);

    });

    return query.createQuery(em, TranslatedLocation.class).getResultList();
}
```

Resulting SQL:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.location,
CASE WHEN (?1 = 1) THEN t1.english ELSE t1.german END AS label

FROM Location t0  INNER JOIN Translation t1  ON (t0.label_id = t1.id)
```

Entity declarations:

```java
@Entity
@Data //lombok
public static class Location {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String location;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "label_id")
    private Translation translation;
}

@Entity
@Data //lombok
public static class Translation {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String english;
    private String german;
}

@Tuple
@Getter //lombok
public static class TranslatedLocation {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String location;
    private String label;
}
```